# Is it possible to deploy Vue and Vite without a server to run?

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have a very particular question, cause I wish to create a webpage that works without a server, and I'm trying to do it using vite, my whole project is using vue + vite.

if I try to use "vite build" command, the page deploy as blank, and the only way I can see the page is if I use "vite preview".

would it be possible, somehow, to load the content of the html page using vite, without needing the "vite preview"? just double clicking on index.html

Comment: you want a file that you download, double-click and it shows all the content that would show when it's hosted??

Comment: I want to double-click on index.html on dist folder and then it shows all the content from my webpage, but vite is making the page blank and throwing some errors.

Comment: as a single-file?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a single-file, I just want to open the Index.html and it has to show me all the content that I've created using vue

Comment: This is how it look's like when I use "vite build" and try to execute the [index.html](https://prnt.sc/wLBCrENnlwTc).
I want it to show like [this](https://prnt.sc/GjYh6pa0rkkK) 
But I don't even know if it's possible

Comment: It's possible with Vue 3 is as easy as it was with Vue 2. As others have pointed out, by setting the public path to an empty string or ./ Vite is now the recommended way anyway. See more here https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#previewing-locally and here https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html

Comment: By the way, double clicking the file itself would open it on `file` protocol, and these are meant to be served over `http` protocol, so you will most likely need a server anyway, not that you can't use it without a server, you probably can by configuring the paths however it's still recommend to use a server, especially for production applications, it will save you a lot of headache, plus you won't be able to do much with static site generation aka SSG.

Answer (score 10):

Using vue-cli, this is possible by setting the publicPath in the vue.config.js file to an empty string, see: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath
I've personally only used it with Vue 2, but from what I read online it should also be possible with Vue 3, if you're okay with switching to vue-cli.

Using Vite, I found this question and answer which shows a way by bundling all the scripts, css and images into a single file:
[How to open a static website in localhost but generated with Vite and without running a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031295/how-to-open-a-static-website-in-localhost-but-generated-with-vite-and-without-ru)

I did try that and it mostly works, but not currently for svg files which I use a lot of in my application. It might work fine for your use-case.

I did also need to add  `"type": "module",` in my package.json to get rid of an error saying

> "Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
> /path/to/dist/index.js from /path/to/vite.config.inlined.ts not
> supported."

Comment: A lot of work for "just" that, well found tho.

Comment: I agree @kissu, I wish it were much easier! Sometimes you have to jump through all the hoops though, such as when you have customers that need to run your app on a computer without network access and don't allow executable files/webservers to run locally.

Comment: @kissu Unfortunately I mostly wind up with such customers. *facepalm* Since they don't allow executables, a web app is the only way to go. Some day we'll have to tell them that they can't have it both ways, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

If you open your page simply as an `index.html`, you will be limited regarding some [API calls and alike](https://superuser.com/a/1008453/850722). Nowadays, you will need a light server to be hosting it via a simple `vite preview` as you saw. This is mainly because the files are being worked with bundlers like Webpack and Vite.

I'm not sure that there is a way of loading the whole thing with just an `index.html` because files like `.vue` are not natively supported, you need a specific loader.

One simple solution would be to [use Vue as a CDN](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools), but it will limit your DX experience regarding [SFC files](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html#why-sfc), but you will be able to use Vue into a regular `index.html` file.
PS: your performance will also be worse overall (because of the required network requests).

If you want something really lightweight, you could of course also use [petite-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue), maybe more suited towards super simple projects with a tiny need of reactivity.

I still recommend using something like Netlify or Vercel, to host your static site for free + having the whole Vue experience thanks to a server running `vite preview` for you.