# Bundle React.js project into single js file that can be embedded in Ghost blog post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ghost-blog

After building a React.js project, I want to bundle all the files (HTML, js, CSS) into a single js file that can be embedded into a ghost blog post.

Here is an example of how this was done for a ghost blog post.

https://blog.openbloc.com/including-a-js-app-in-a-ghost-post/

My question is how do I bundle the React.js project files into a single file that can be deployed in a ghost blog post?

This can be successfully done for Vue.js but I am not sure if it can be done for React.js

[Bundle Vue project into single js file that can be embedded in Ghost blog post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71262487/bundle-vue-project-into-single-js-file-that-can-be-embedded-in-ghost-blog-post)

I am using the React v18

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Creating a single JS file output

1. Scaffold a [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) project with the React template:

   ```bash
   npm init vite my-react-project -- --template react
   ```
2. Install [`vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js?activeTab=readme) to automatically inject the app's styles into the document `<head>`:

   ```bash
   cd my-react-project
   npm i -D vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js
   ```
3. Configure Vite to use that plugin via [`plugins`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#plugins); and to disable CSS code splitting via [`build.cssCodeSplit`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-csscodesplit):

   ```js
   // vite.config.js
   import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
   import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from 'vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js'

   export default defineConfig({
     plugins: [
       cssInjectedByJsPlugin(),
     ],
     build: {
       cssCodeSplit: false,
     },
   })
   ```
4. Configure Vite to build a single JavaScript file (i.e., the `main.jsx` file) via [`build.rollupOptions.input`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-rollupoptions):

   ```js
   // vite.config.js
   import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

   export default defineConfig({
     build: {
       rollupOptions: {
         input: {
           app: './src/main.jsx',
         },
       },
     },
   })
   ```
5. Configure Vite to specify the deployment target's base URL via [`base`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#base):

   ```js
   // vite.config.js
   import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

   export default defineConfig({
     base: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tony19-sandbox/vite-react-single-js-file/dist/',
   })
   ```

   The base URL is ideally a CDN link for optimum load performance. For example, if the app files were hosted on GitHub at `https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vite-react-single-js-file/tree/main/dist`, the CDN link would be `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tony19-sandbox/vite-react-single-js-file/dist/`.
6. Build the app:

   ```bash
   cd my-react-project
   npm run build
   ```

   The build then produces a `dist` directory containing these files:

   ```
   dist/assets/app.d91c60c0.js
   dist/assets/logo.ecc203fb.svg
   ```

### Usage in Ghost

1. In your blog page, insert a [custom HTML block](https://ghost.org/help/using-the-editor/#adding-custom-html).

[image]

2. In the HTML block, add a `div` with an ID that matches the mounting point in `src/main.jsx` from your app's original source (the default ID is `"root"`).

   ```html
   <div id="root">App loading...</div>
   ```
3. Add a `<script>` that pulls in the `app.js` file previously built. For example, if you've hosted the script on GitHub, you could use a CDN link like this:

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tony19-sandbox/vite-react-single-js-file/dist/assets/app.d91c60c0.js"></script>
   ```

The result looks like this:

[image]

[GitHub](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vite-react-single-js-file)

[Ghost page](https://react-app-in-ghost.ghost.io/p/bcab0f9f-070c-4dbf-bfed-11edf121d38a/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gulp` for bundling react project into a single file.
Steps:

1. Install dependencies `npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-inline-source gulp-replace`
2. Create a `.env` file which will disable source maps.

   ```
   INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false
   GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
   SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
   ```
3. Create `gulpfile.js` file in the root folder and write this in it.

   ```js
   const gulp = require('gulp');
   const inlinesource = require('gulp-inline-source');
   const replace = require('gulp-replace');

   gulp.task('default', () => {
     return gulp
       .src('./build/*.html')
       .pipe(replace('.js"></script>', '.js" inline></script>'))
       .pipe(replace('rel="stylesheet">', 'rel="stylesheet" inline>'))
       .pipe(
         inlinesource({
           compress: false,
           ignore: ['png'],
        })
       )
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
   });
   ```
4. Now run `npm run build` to create an optimized production build and then run `npx gulp` to bundle all the JS and CSS files in the static build folder into the single main html file.